# Bottom-up well-balanced mergesort

Tags: algorithms, sorting, recursion

If you implement mergesort top-down you can always split the input of length $n$ into one of length $\lfloor n / 2\rfloor$ and one of length $\lceil n / 2 \rceil$. This ensures that all merges are always *well-balanced*: the left and right inputs differ in length by at most 1.

Is there a way of achieving this property in a bottom-up stable mergesort (that is, only merging adjacent subarrays) using some clever arithmetic?

It's possible of course if you use a stack and effectively simulate the top-down algorithm, but what if you were limited to $O(1)$ memory for computing the merge indices?

To abstract away the mergesort we can also state the problem as such: given $O(1)$ memory and a number $n$, generate a series of triples $(i, j, k)$ such that:

- for each triple we have $0 \leq i < j < k \leq n$,
- for each triple we have $|(j - i) - (k - j)| \leq 1$,
- the last triple is $(0, x, n)$ for some $x$,
- if $(i, j, x)$ is in the list and $j - i > 1$, then $(i, y, j)$ must precede it for some $y$,
- if $(x, j, k)$ is in the list and $k - j > 1$, then $(j, y, k)$ must precede it for some $y$.

If the above constraints are met calling $\operatorname{merge}(A[i..j], A[j..k])$ for each triple would sort $A[0..n]$, while being a well-balanced mergesort.

Comment: It seems that [A110316](https://oeis.org/A110316) is of interest here, which I found by counting the number of possible solutions per $n$.

Comment: How would you merge $A[i..j]$ and $A[j..k]$ in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ space? In-place mergesort is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm), but it requires to create unbalanced subarrays.

Comment: @Nathaniel You may assume $\operatorname{merge}$ is a black-box operator whose memory budget is none of your concern. I'm just interested if the sequence of indices itself could be generated without extra memory/a recursion stack.

Comment: Noted. Also, you talk about a list of triples, but in order to do it in $\mathcal{O}(1)$, I suppose that you would like a generator rather than a list?

Comment: @Nathaniel Sure, I mean a series in the logical sense, not in a physical sense in memory. A loop that calls a `merge` function on each iteration would work, for example.